# Change font family for one column in Data Table in shiny app

Tags: css, r, fonts, shiny

I am developing shiny app for showing tables and I use the package DT. I need one column in my code to show barcodes, I thought that it should be possible to change only font to show barcode, but I have no idea. Here is part of my code

```
    datatable(d1, filter = "top",rownames = T, extensions = 'Buttons',editable=list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(1:10))),
              options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                             buttons = c('copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'), pageLength = 100,
                             columnDefs = list(list(targets = 11, visible = FALSE)))) %>%
      formatStyle(
        'HELP',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'lightyellow1'))
      )%>%
      formatStyle('ID', target = 'column',    #here I start tested something
        fontFamily="arial")                          # this posibility doesnt exist

  }
  )
```

Many thanks for help

Comment: For me it works but I use `target = 'cell'` because `target = 'column'` does not work with my DT version.